# Training Naive Bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

I am developing a *naive bayes classifier* using simple bag of words concept. My question is in naive bayes or in any other machine learning senario *'training'* the classifier is an important matter. But how to train naive bayes classifier when I already have a bag_of_words of various classes.

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](https://www.bionicspirit.com/blog/2012/02/09/howto-build-naive-bayes-classifier.html)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have read the turorial. But a question still remains. Suppose I have two classes positive and negative. Now in my training data set of postive class I have a no. of positive strings and in negative class I also have a no. of negative strings. But in positive strings not all the words are postive. There the problem arises. When I try to take words from them and put them in postive bag_of_words then some negative words are also being added which hampers the later classification.

Comment: @Pritam is the positive or negative slant of the words depending of the context? If so you need to add the context as features in your `X` vector for each sample (word). Otherwise, how would the classifier be able to distinguish?

Answer (score 1):

> how to train naive bayes classifier when I already have a bag_of_words of various classes.

In general, what you do is this:

1. split your bag of words into two random subsets, call one `training` the other `test`
2. train the classifier on the `training` subset
3. validate the classifier's accuracy by running it against the `test` subset

> 'training' the classifier is an important matter

indeed -- that's how your classifier learns to separate words from different classes.

Comment: Sir is there any rejection criteria where we can reject naive bayes and use svm or maximum entropy classifier instead of that while analyzing a string or a document?

Answer (score 0):

[The Stanford IR book](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html) gives a good explanation of how Naive Bayes classifiers work, and they use text classification as their example. [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Examples) also gives a detailed description of the theory and some concrete examples.

In a nutshell, you count the occurrences of each word type within each class, and then normalize by the number of documents to get the probability of word given class p(w|c). You then use Bayes' rule to get the probability of each class given the document p(c|doc) = p(c)*p(doc|c), where the probability of the document given the class is the product of the probabilities of its words given the class p(doc|c) = Π(w in doc)  p(w|c). These probabilities get very small before normalizing between the classes, so you may want to take the logarithm and sum them to avoid underflow errors.

Comment: Sir is there any rejection criteria where we can reject naive bayes and use svm or maximum entropy classifier instead of that while analyzing a string or a document?